# Append the publication name after every Page Title in SDL tridion

Tags: c#, xcode, content-management-system, tridion

I need to implement a code wherein I have to append the publication name (which are multiple in number and list of which is maintained in tridion under "Categories and Keywords" like UK,Spain,France etc.) after every Page Title in SDL tridion, like for eg. If my page is  a product page and that product is a dispenser the tab opened in the browser should display the page title as follows:"Paper dispenser | Tork Spain" where Spain is the publication name contained in the list and Tork should be appended too before every publication name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably several ways to achieve this, but the way I would go about it would be to have your publication name Keyword (eg. Spain) set in your publication metadata.

Then you should be able to use a custom TBB to add this as an `appSetting` when the web.config is published.

The deployed web app can then use this setting to append the country to the title.

I hope this helps and that I have understood your question correctly!